# C# media query for specific max-width in firefox

Tags: c#, css, firefox, media-queries

What I am trying to get is a media query that only triggers in Firefox and only until the window reaches a max-width of 1352px. 
I've tried different versions like

```
@@-moz-document url-prefix() and media only screen and (max-width: 1352px) {
    #timetable {
        transform: scale(0.85) !important
    }
```

or

```
@@media only screen and (max-width: 1352px) and (moz-document: url-prefix()) {
    #timetable {
        transform: scale(0.85) !important
    }
```

but unfortunately both won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code will work**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()  {
@media screen and (max-width: 1352px) {
   #timetable {
    transform: scale(0.85) !important
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For some reason it actually didn't, but changing the order of media screen and -moz-document did. Nevertheless I will accept this, since it pointed me directly to the solution. Thanks :)